# Select smallest values from rows with couple parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, parameters, sql-order-by

I have SQL statement:

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from table1
group by col1,col2,col3,col4
```

to produce the below table:

[image]

I want to display just rows, with smallest values for the same parameters.
Result should be as below:

[image]

How to write it?

**UPDATE**: year, month
[image]

Comment: `group by col1,col2,col3,col4` produces *exactly one* row per `col1,col2,col3,col4`. How come you get the result cited above?

Comment: sorry my mistake, without group by

Comment: I think you could use HAVING

Something like HAVING Col5 = MIN(Col5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below.

```
SELECT  Year
       ,Month
       ,COL1
       ,COL2
       ,COL3
       ,COL4
       ,COL5
FROM 
    (SELECT  Year
            ,Month
            ,COL1
            ,COL2
            ,COL3
            ,COL4
            ,COL5
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COL4 ORDER BY COL5) AS RN
     FROM table1) AS X
WHERE X.RN = 1
```

Comment: what if need to also group by it by col: year, month?

Comment: Please show some sample data with year & month also

Comment: just updated question: I thnik I need to add to row_number: col4,year,month, but Im not sure...

Comment: I have did as: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COL4, Year, Month ORDER BY COL5) and is working!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, it should be simply this:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, min(col5)
from table1
group by col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MIN() with OVER clause to all rows with min value for set:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    col5,
    min(col5) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4) AS min_for_columns_set
FROM table1
```

UPD: 
Only min values for group set:

```
    SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    min(col5) as min_value
FROM table1
group BY col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Comment: @ZoharPeled Indeed. added obvious variant with GROUP BY fields set

Comment: your second query would still return all the rows of the table, but now you will get col5 again with the title min_value ...

Comment: @ZoharPeled I accidently added fifth column to group by and partition by, thank you for mentioned it

Comment: ok, after your edit your second query will raise an error - columns in the select clause must appear in the group by clause or in an aggregation function - you left col5 in the select list... :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am totally inaccurate today >_< will go for some coffee) thank you again :)

Comment: Well, we all have these days :-) now your query seems fine, at least...